# resolving an NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile error

Tags: objective-c, nsurlerrordomain

I wrote some code to download a URL to my disk, using an NSURLRequest and an NSURLDownload. The download starts fine (at least, it sends `downloadDidBegin:(NSURLDownload *)download`), but then it sends

```
-(void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

My implementation of the function is as follows:

```
{
[download release];

NSLog(@"Download failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

The logged error is

2011-07-17 01:48:43.194 URLDownloader[28031:903] Download failed! Error - The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -3001.) [the URL in the NSURLRequest]

From what I can tell, this is the NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile error. I cannot find any explanation of why this error occurs, other then "Returned when NSURLDownload was unable to open the downloaded file on disk." from the documentation. So, why is this happening?

Fact that might be helpful(?): NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile is enumerated as kCFURLErrorCannotOpenFile. I have no idea what this means either....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I was just being foolish. I had created a path using NSURL's absoluteString method instead of the path method. This was just bad coding on my part...